# Change value of a class variable with one click? (simplest way)

Tags: javascript, class, firefox-addon

I'm looking for a way to easily change one of variable's value. There's a chat in a browser game that I want to make taller. Changing height in dev tools does the work:

```
<div class="tsbchat" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 160px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
```

But can I make i.e. a script and put it in bookmarks that will allow me to change this value with one click? How would it look like? I know it's a trivial question but I'm a noob, you can remove the question and I will find help somewhere else. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what you want to change in selected element ?

Comment: the easiest way is to type document.getElementsByClassName('tsbchat')[0].style.height=['your height here']  in console

Comment: @CodeManiac I want to change the element's height

Comment: @h-des this didn't do a thing except for saying 'Array [ "300" ]'. Perhaps you need more code? Go to this page https://www.playok.com/en/kalamburos/# and click on 'new game table', there you'll find the chat.

Comment: @Kajto well you can check answer i added a demo.

Comment: So far I think @h-des has been the closest to my answer, but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: @Kajto 
document.getElementsByClassName('tsbchat')[0].style.height='600px' works for me

Comment: It works indeed... I forgot to add px. Well that's it for now, make it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to type

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tsbchat')[0].style.height='600px'
```

in your console.

Remember to add [0], because `getElementsByClassName` returns an array

Answer (score 0):

**For using a javascript function as bookmark you need to use `bookmarklet`.You can read up more here about it [Bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).**

For example.

```
javascript:( alert(' Hello i am clicked from bookmark '));
```

Add this to destination of bookmark. so as soon as you click on bookmark you will see a `Hello i am clicked from bookmark` alert.

***You can do it like this***

Here handleClick is a function which will be called when you click on div.Than we select the element by class name and change it's style.

```js
function handleClick(){
  let element = document.getElementsByClassName('tsbchat');
  element[0].style.height = "1000px"; //chnage to amount you want
}
```

```css
.tsbchat{
  position : relative;
  width : 100%;
  height : 160px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="tsbchat" onclick="handleClick()">Hello</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you must've misunderstood me, I'm modifying the values on external site temporarily (like hacking, but I'm sure it's legal). By one click I meant clicking on a bookmark with a javascript in it for example.

Comment: @Kajto i have updated my answer.check i think this is what you wanted to do.

Comment: Guys, I probably messed up while typing my question and you totally don't get me:). I'm looking for something far more simple. I just need to modify that height on that page (I'm not creating something new) with some of the most basic javascript commmands. Then I will put it inside a toolbar so it acts like a button in my browser, that's it.

Comment: @Kajto if you read up properly this is what i have added in update.

Comment: @Kajto All you need to do is just copy paste the js `javascript:(document.getElementsByClassName('tsbchat').style.height="100px")` at place of destination in bookmark.

Comment: While executing the script I'm getting an error: TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).style is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using jQuery

```js
function handleClick(){
  $(".tsbchat").css("height", "100px"); //choose the amount you want
}
```

```css
.tsbchat{
  position : relative;
  width : 100%;
  height : 160px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="tsbchat" onclick="handleClick()">Hello</div>
</body>
```

This way you can make bigger your div but only once
Use this script instead if you need to use several times:

```
function handleClick(){
    $(".tsbchat").css("height", function(){
                        return $(".tsbchat").css() + 100;
                      });

}
```

Note: not sure if this way you have to specify the "px" but i'm quite sure this works

Comment: Please refer to my comments underneath the other answers, this in not what I'm looking for. I appreciate your help but I need some more feedback. Thanks!